# Interent Connection stop and reconnets intermittently, while ping requests go through

Tags: networking, router, internet, ping, isp

Good day all

I will keep this short,  for the past week my internet has started becoming jittery,

It will work fine then suddenly it will "go off", how I know this is my google drive says cannot connect and my teamspeak hangs then says connection lost,

but, on my teamspeak, it will connect to server, then fail, then try to reconnect for 5-10 times, then eventually reconnect for 3 min, then disconnect again

Here is the catch, I am able to download torrents and am able to ping google no matter if my internet disconnects, ping requests go through constantly with NO increase in ping

when I try to go online to e.g. google, it hangs for about 5 min. then responds with connection to server has been reset, it is the same with any website (except 9gag, I found so far is not affected)

This will go on for anything from 3 hours to 8 hours (usually comes right overnight, not sure when - early morning or late night)

My ISP just "resets" my port, it works fine for 2 hours then goes back to it problematic state

ANyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to isolate the error to see if it is a problem with your computer, network, or Internet connection.

1. Does this behavior happen to any other devices on your network?  Try connecting with another PC or mobile device and see if they have the same behavior at the same time.  If other devices work fine, then you have to troubleshoot the PC.  Update your NIC drivers, run malware scans, reinstall your browsers and other applications.   Check to make sure you are using the correct DNS servers.  You can also try testing with free DNS servers like google's 8.8.8.8.  Disable any software firewall and see if that fixes the issue.
2. If your router is separate from your modem, try rebooting the router.  Make sure the firmware is up to date.  If you are wireless, try and see if you can replicate the problem when you are plugged in through a wired connection, bypassing any switches you may have.  If you have a second wireless router, make sure it is setup as an access-point to avoid issues with double-NAT.  Plug your computer directly into your Internet connection bypassing your router and see if you still have a problem.  If your router is the problem, either update the firmware if you haven't already or consider replacing it.
3. If you have determined it isn't a problem with your computer, router, DNS settings, network equipment etc, contact your ISP's NOC and see if they are having outages or peering problems with other network.  You may have to replace your modem if you have one.  Comcast used to use the Netgear cg3000dcr, for example, which had a bug that caused packet loss for those who had a block of IPs, for example.

Comment: thanks @pooter03 1. THis happens on all devices on the network 2. I only have a router, tried reseting/rebooting, its all the same 3. Im thinking of giving them a call and raging ;) Hopefully it is a problem on their side, but thnx

Comment: Out of curiosity, who is your ISP and what is the model of the router you are using?